# shared library c++ linux loading non virtual functions

Tags: c++, linux, shared

I have a shared library which has a base class which has pure virtual functions as well some more functions are implemented which are common to derived classes.
 Base class  TestAbstract.h

```
#ifndef TEST_ABSTRACT_H_
#define TEST_ABSTRACT_H_

class CAbstract
{
public:
        CAbstract();
        virtual ~CAbstract();

        virtual int abstractmethod() = 0;
        int test() ;
};
```

TestAbstract.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include "TestAbstract.h"

using namespace std;

CAbstract::CAbstract()
{
        cout << "CAbstract Base constructor" << endl;
}

CAbstract::~CAbstract()
{
        cout << "CAbstract Base destructor" << endl;
}
int CAbstract::test()
{
        cout << "CAbastract::test non-virtual function call from Base, implemented only in Base class" << endl;
        return 0;
}
```

Derived class implementation
DerivedFromAbstract.h

```
 #pragma once
    #include "TestAbstract.h"
    class CDerivedFromAbstract :
            public CAbstract
    {
    public:
            CDerivedFromAbstract(void);
            ~CDerivedFromAbstract(void);

            int abstractmethod();
            void derivedTest();
    };
```

DerivedFromAbstract.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include "DerivedFromAbstract.h"

using namespace std;

CDerivedFromAbstract::CDerivedFromAbstract(void)
{
        cout << "CDerivedFromAbstract::CDerivedFromAbstract " << endl;
}


CDerivedFromAbstract::~CDerivedFromAbstract(void)
{
        cout << "CDerivedFromAbstract::~CDerivedFromAbstract " << endl;
}

int CDerivedFromAbstract::abstractmethod()
{
        cout << "CDerivedFromAbstract::abstractmethod overriden in derived class" << endl;
        return 0;
}
```

void CDerivedFromAbstract::derivedTest()
{
        cout << "CDerivedFromAbstract::derivedTest non-virtual function call from Derived" << endl;
}
ObjectInterface.h

```
/*ObjectInterface.h
 *
 *  Created on: Jan 4, 2018
 *      Author: root
 */

#ifndef INCLUDE_OBJECTINTERFACE_H_
#define INCLUDE_OBJECTINTERFACE_H_

#include "TestAbstract.h"


// the types of the class factories

extern "C" CAbstract* create_t();
extern "C" void destroy_t(CAbstract*);


#endif /*INCLUDE_OBJECTINTERFACE_H_ */
```

ObjectInterface.cpp

```
/*
 * ObjectInterface.cpp
 *
 *  Created on: Jan 4, 2018
 *      Author: root
 */
#include "Objectinterface.h"
#include "TestAbstract.h"
#include "DerivedFromAbstract.h"

// the types of the class factories
extern "C" CAbstract* create_t()
 {
      return new CDerivedFromAbstract();

 }

 extern "C" void destroy_t(CAbstract* pObj)
 {
         if(pObj)
         {
                 delete pObj;
         }
 }
```

Generated so with the following options

> g++ -fPIC -shared -rdynamic TestAbstract.cpp DerivedFromAbstract.cpp
>   Objectinterface.cpp -o abstracttest.so

Main program that loads the .so is

```
 #include <dlfcn.h>
    #include <iostream>
    #include "DerivedFromAbstract.h"

    using namespace std;

    typedef CAbstract* create_t();
    typedef void destroy_t(CAbstract*);

    int main(int argc, char **argv)
    {
      /* on Linux, use "./myclass.so" */
      void* handle = dlopen("./abstracttest.so", RTLD_LAZY);

            if(handle)
            {
            cout <<"so handle available" << endl;

            create_t* creat=(create_t*)dlsym(handle,"create_t");
            destroy_t* destroy=(destroy_t*)dlsym(handle,"destroy_t");

            if( creat)
                    {
                    cout << " calling create" << endl;
                    CAbstract* myClass = creat();
                    cout <<"calling abstractmethod" << endl;
                    myClass->abstractmethod();
                    dynamic_cast<CDerivedFromAbstract*>(myClass)->derivedTest();
                    destroy( myClass );
                    }
            }
            dlclose(handle);
    }
```

> g++ main.cpp -o stub -ldl
>   I get the error
>
> /tmp/ccKvXgLa.o: In function `main': main.cpp:(.text+0xe9): undefined
>   reference to`typeinfo for CDerivedFromAbstract'
>   main.cpp:(.text+0xfe): undefined reference to
>   `CDerivedFromAbstract::derivedTest()' collect2: error: ld returned 1
>   exit status

Is there any way I can access the base class non virtual functions in my client application/stub which is loading the shared library.

I am able to call the virtual function, but not the non-virtual function.

Please let me know, if anyone has faced this issue. I am new to Linux, let me know if I am missing some simple concept.

Thanks

Comment: As long as the header matches and you are supposed to be able, then it should be fine. What error? Private? Not exported?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question but I don't think it has anything to do with Linux.  In C++ derived classes inherit from the base class regardless of which OS you're using.  Pure virtual functions must be implemented by the derived class.

Comment: What specific errors are you getting?

Comment: @Kenny Ostrom , it is public member function. As I told, I am new to Linux shared libraries, please tell me if I am missing something to add for exporting. I am accessing the class object and trying to access the function with object.

Comment: @Justin Randall, yes pure virtual function I have implemented in derived class, I do not face any issue with that. I will try to write a small sample and post the code here that would explain more clearly.

Comment: @n.m. I am getting the error "Test.cpp:(.text+0x1b8): undefined reference to `DerivedClass::memberfn()'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status"

Comment: Please post a [mcve]. This includes your build command.

Comment: I don't see `derivdTest()` defined anywhere. Even if it is defined, you cannot call it this way. Non-virtual members are just regular functions as far as the calling mechanism goes. You need to `dlsym` them exactly like you `dlsym` your `extern "C"` functions (with all the problems of name mangling).

Comment: @n.m. While copying the code, I have missed copying it. I get the errors after having the definition only. And the same concept works fine in windows. Here I am accessing the class object and not the functions directly. If I use extern "C", I am worried,  how does C++ concepts like virtual functions and overriding will work. I also understand that ideally I cannot instantiate abstract class to access methods. But I should be able to access with derived class object right?

Comment: You are doing something very wrong. "And the same concept works fine in windows" No, it cannot, you are doing something else on Windows. "Here I am accessing the class object and not the functions directly" You are mistaken. "If I use extern "C", I am worried, how does C++ concepts like virtual functions and overriding will work" Member functions cannot be extern C, you need to find some other solution. "eally I cannot instantiate abstract class to access methods" Neither ideally nor in any other way, simply never. Your whole approach is broken, you need to rethink it.

Answer (score 0):

No, there is no way to access non-virtual function in the class you import through `dlopen` .

Because of early binding, every non-virtual function you call should determine its symbol at compiling, while virtual function searches its symbol at runtime through vtable/vptr. You should declare `derivedTest` as virtual if you want to call it in main.cpp.

Checkout this link which demonstrates a detailed example of loading class through dlopen:
[C++ dlopen mini HOWTO](https://tldp.org/HOWTO/C++-dlopen/thesolution.html)